# Alternative implementations of "remember my device" that do not use cookies?

Tags: security, web-applications, web

I am working on adding a "remember my device" feature to a web application I maintain for a financial services company. All implementations of this feature that I've read about use persistent cookies, and my existing "remember me" feature uses persistent cookies.

In testing my current bank's (chase.com) implementation using Win7/IE11 I found I could not delete cookies and force my bank to forget my device. I tried a new machine with Win7/IE9 and proceeded to have the site remember the device. I then tried the following in any and all combinations:

- clear cookies and all browsing history elements (not preserving favorites)
- reset IE to default
- reset IE to default and clear personal data

I also uninstalled Flash, Java and .NET runtimes in the hopes that data was being stored in these plugin platforms. I did find some .js files that references Flash cookies so I thought without Flash the site would default back to normal cookies. I tested with IE since it does not have Flash built in like Chrome does.

I also logged off/on after each clear cache attempt to ensure IE processes were closed in between attempts. After all of this, my browser is still a remembered device.

My questions are:

- Is there any other client-side technology that could be used to remember my device that I am not resetting/clearing?
- Would enough details be able to be logged on the server to create a device fingerprint that is sufficiently accurate? I have never had my bank re-prompt me to remember my device after upgrading or installing plugins, etc. (Granted I normally use Chrome and am only using IE for this analysis)
- Would a purely server-side approach be recommended, particularly for a financial institution like Chase? Are there any writeups or articles that address the pros/cons of such an approach? I'm imagining it to be less secure than the standard cookie approach.

Thank you all, my first question, apologies if my google-fu failed to turn up an obvious answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are several client-side methods for persisting data available in HTML5. A good overview is at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of some of these, like File System. According to the article the only method IE9 supports is Web Storage. Wouldn't this be reset when performing an IE reset to default?

Comment: [Here](http://sharonminsuk.com/blog/2011/03/21/clearing-cache-has-no-effect-on-html5-localstorage-or-sessionstorage/) is a good discussion on clearing local and session storage in various browsers. Sometimes clearing cookies will do it, but not always.

Comment: Also interesting is the discussion at the bottom of that page about tracking with etags, and well as the recent publicity about [Verizon's "super cookie"](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2014/11/verizon-x-uidh), using an X-UIDH header.

Comment: As an update, the link provided for the discussion on clearing local and session storage was tested on my IE9 instance. All stored items were cleared upon clearing cache, which still leaves me stumped as to where chase.com is storing it's "mark" to remember my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/)

There the above page has info and a button to actually test it.
It'll show you which of the methods it uses works (if any) in a particular device/browser.

And the [code itself is available at github](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie)

Comment: This is really fascinating! Thanks for the link.